# How to prevent using anything except application in Delphi XE

Tags: forms, delphi, desktop, delphi-xe

I'm developing a **VCL Form Application**

When the application started

I need to **prevent** the **user** of the computer to do anything

**He can't** close the application by **ALT+F4** or **CTRL+ALT+DEL**

**He can't** change to another window by **ALT+Tab**

**He can't** Go to the desktop by clicking **Windows + D**

This will used in **Cyber Cafe** and it is a **Server**/**Client** application

so before the Admin in the Server giving access to the Client, He can't do anything in the computer .. just a full screen for my form

Comment: Use the OS kiosk mode

Comment: ok, i'm going to check about it, thanks

Comment: Google for kiosk mode


https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=windows%20kiosk%20mode

Comment: Is that Google mode going to work in my Delphi XE Application ?

Comment: @SystemDZ: Jens was not telling you to use Google in your app, but was instead telling you to use Google to search for information on how to put your Windows OS into kiosk mode. For example: [How to Easily Put a Windows PC into Kiosk Mode With Assigned Access](http://www.howtogeek.com/173562/how-to-easily-put-a-windows-pc-into-kiosk-mode-with-assigned-access/)

Comment: Thanks for explaining @RemyLebeau
I'm going to check about that
But, This application should do the same thing in any computer not just my PC

Comment: I'm not sure that a Application can prevent System Shortcuts like **CTRL+ALT+DEL**

Comment: That's correct, But there is an applications like HandyCafe & EasyCafe doing that !

Comment: Why would you not want a kiosk? What's the downside of using the feature designed to solve your problem?

Comment: And I guess the HandyCafe/EasyCafe solutions are using that kiosk mode too

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i have no problem, i just was asking if there is a another easy way to do that, Thanks

Comment: @SirRufo that's good to know, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the login system of Windows that traps the CTRL-ALT-DEL combination (and so it is not accessible to user applications), you will need to change the system's keyboard scancode map to ignore at least one of those keys.

First you have to ensure Autologon on your computer, else you can login.  This could also be done in the registry.

Then the tricky part editing the scancode map. In MSDN you'll find an article about how to do: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I've found this reg file that is suppose to disable **CTRL + ALT + DELETE** but I havent tested it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,38,00,00,00,38,e0,\
  00,00,00,00
```

Be aware that this is extremely hirisk. Both using the REG file and changing the scancode map. I suggest you test your stuff in a virtual Machine.

You also need to prevent the user from shuttingdown the computer. Which is also done in registry:

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
System Key: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
Value Name: NoClose
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (0 = shutdown enabled, 1 = shutdown disabled)
```

So inorder for shuttingdown the computer your probram must make a call to ShutdownwindowsEx

```
function ExitWindows(iFlags: Integer): Boolean;
var
  osVerInfo: TOSVersionInfo;

  function SetPrivilege(sPrivilegeName: string; bEnabled: Boolean): Boolean;
  var
    TPPrev, TP: TTokenPrivileges;
    Token: THandle;
    dwRetLen: DWord;
  begin
    Result := False;
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES or TOKEN_QUERY, Token);
    TP.PrivilegeCount := 1;
    if (LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, PChar(sPrivilegeName), TP.Privileges[0].LUID)) then
    begin
      if (bEnabled) then
        TP.Privileges[0].Attributes := SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED
      else
        TP.Privileges[0].Attributes := 0;
      dwRetLen := 0;
      Result := AdjustTokenPrivileges(Token, False, TP, sizeof(TPPrev), TPPrev, dwRetLen);
    end;
    CloseHandle(Token);
  end;

begin
  Result := True;
  osVerInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize := sizeof(TOSVersionInfo);
  if GetVersionEx(osVerInfo) then
    case osVerInfo.dwPlatformId of
      VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS:
        if not ExitWindowsEx(iFlags, 0) then
          Result := False; // handle errors...
      VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT:
        if SetPrivilege('SeShutdownPrivilege', True) then
        begin
          if not ExitWindowsEx(iFlags, 0) then
            Result := False; // handle errors...
          SetPrivilege('SeShutdownPrivilege', False)
        end
        else
          Result := False; // handle errors...
    else
      Result := False;
    end;
end;
```